# Select prev value in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hiveql

I'm been poking at this for a while and haven't had luck. I have a table like the below. I'm trying to get the col value prior to the first text value per user. I'm on Hive.

```
user    ts            col      isnumber
1       1473811200    5         y
1       1473811205    10        y
1       1473811207    15        y
1       1473811212    text1     n
1       1473811215    text2     n
1       1473811225    30        y
2       1473811201    10        y
2       1473811205    text3     n
2       1473811207    20        y
2       1473811210    30        y
```

Output should be:

```
user    col
1       15
2       10
```

Comment: can you use 'lag'?

Comment: First of all you need some id/timestamp column to get stable sort.

Comment: @DanielMarcus can you write it out?

Comment: sure but first i need to know if lag is supported in your rdbms and also what @lad2025 said

Comment: @lad2025 there is a unix timestamp col that i can get. can you suggest how it would be done?

Comment: @DanielMarcus yes lag is supported

Comment: OK please update data set with timestamp and we should be able to solve for you

Comment: @DanielMarcus added unix timestamp

Comment: Does @lad2025 answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using windowed functions:

```
SELECT user_, prev
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_ ORDER BY ts) AS rn
      FROM (SELECT *, CASE 
                WHEN isnumber = 'y' THEN NULL
                WHEN LAG(isnumber,1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_ ORDER BY ts) = 'y'
                     THEN LAG(col,1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_ ORDER BY ts)
               END AS prev
             FROM tab) sub
    WHERE prev IS NOT NULL) sub2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca2f414042ff7cb795b65028215f7684)**

Comment: Nice one - more complex than I thought